# Listen to insert/update events on a simple Table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a simple Table definition:

```
my_table = Table(
    'table_name', db.Model.metadata,
    Column('id1', Integer, ForeignKey('other1.id'), nullable=False),
    Column('id2', Integer, ForeignKey('other2.id'), nullable=False)
)
```

And I want to register for `before_insert` and `before_update` events on it.

However, I could not find any such examples and wonder if its necassiry. Trying to explicitly call `event.listen` will fail with an error, and in debugger I can see that the table class only have following events to listen to:

```
 'after_create',
 'after_drop',
 'after_parent_attach',
 'before_create',
 'before_drop',
 'before_parent_attach',
 'column_reflect'
```

Is there a way to listen on the Table without converting it to a full blown model?

Comment: Aren't those two ORM events? On the other hand you're working with a core table.

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing that's just impossible

Answer (score 0):

Try `listens_for`. Seems to work for me!

```
@sa.event.listens_for(my_table, 'after_create') 
def after_create_my_table(target, connection, **kw): 
    pass
```